# Python: how do I iterate only if value is a tuple/list and not a string

Tags: python

I am currently trying to write a python script/small app that is supposed to read events, and then translate them to a different format.
I am also making us of this to dabble a bit in object oriented programming but I am far from an an expert.

I am trying to use a dictionary as map to define the mapping between the source fields and the translated fields.

One of the source fields though (priority in the example) is required twice in the output.

```
class event():
    def __init__(self, description, priority):
        self.description = description
        self.priority = priority

        pass

    _translateMap = {
       'description': 'message',
       'priority' : ('priority', 'severity')
    }

    def translate(self):
       result = {}
       for key, value in self._translateMap.items():
           for field in value:
               result[field] = getattr(self, key)

       return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event1 = event('blahblah','3')
    print event1.translate()
```

this will print:
`{'a': 'blahblah', 'e': 'blahblah', 'severity': '3', 'g': 'blahblah', 'm': 'blahblah', 'priority': '3', 's': 'blahblah'}`

what I would like to have though is:
`{'message': 'blahblah', 'severity': '3', 'priority': '3'}`

I understand that the problem is iterating through every character of 'message', I am not really sure though what is the best way to avoid this while still being able to parse multiple input values?

or is my expectation that they should work similarly is fundamentally wrong?
As mentioned I'm not very experienced yet so if you think the approach doesn't make sense let me know!

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You could check for the type, e.g. with `isinstance(object, str)` or, possibly better, `isinstance(object, (str, bytes))`.

Comment: Could you put 'message' in a tuple or array? like `'description': ('message')`

Comment: @DeltaMarine101 `('message')` is a string, `('message',)` is a tuple: it's the commas that create a tuple, the parentheses are only required when it'd be ambiguous without them, or to create an empty tuple.

Comment: @PM2Ring My bad :/

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you could fix this, you can make the 'message' string into a tuple, so your `_translateMap` would look like this:

```
_translateMap = {
    'description': ('message',),
    'priority' : ('priority', 'severity')
}
```

Otherwise, you could check the type with `isinstance` each time like this:

```
def translate(self):
    result = {}
    for key, value in self._translateMap.items():
        if isinstance(value,str):
            result[value] = getattr(self, key)
        else:
            for field in value:
                 result[field] = getattr(self, key)

    return result
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I changed all the values to tuples and it should work.
I tried to do that  before, but i didn't realize there is supposed to be a comma at the end when you only have one value..

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Consider accepting one of the answers you received (click the tick ✓ next to your favorite answer) :)

Comment: @Eav its actually the comma that notates a tuple and not the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether the value is a string using isinstance:

```
def translate(self):
    result = {}
    for key, value in self._translateMap.items():
        if isinstance(value,str):
            result[value] = getattr(self, key)
        else:
            for field in value:
                result[field] = getattr(self, key)

    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have `pass` in the `init` dunder method. - Also, indentation is the most important aspect when it comes to python since it interprets code based on the latter. - You can pass numbers to functions without using single quotes (string).

You can do something on the lines of:

```
def translate(self):
   return {field: getattr(self, value) for value, field in self._translateMap.items()}
```

Although I don't understand why you set the `priority` field as a tuple, you can do something like:

```
class event():
    _translateMap = {
        'description': 'message',
        'priority': 'priority',
        'severity': 'severity'
    }


    def __init__(self, description, priority, severity):
        self.description = description
        self.priority = priority
        self.severity = severity

    def translate(self):
       return {field: getattr(self, value) for value, field in self._translateMap.items()}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event1 = event('blahblah', 3, 5)
    print(event1.translate())
```

Give attention to how the numbers are not passed as strings and also if you'd like to add checks to the `translate` function you can.

Comment: Thanks for the info, yeah I need to look up exactly when to use pass and yield is on my todo list :)
The reason priority and severity are in a tuple is because there is no severity field in the original event. It's only generated during the translation

Comment: May I suggest a book that might help you? read 'Python Cookbook - Third Edition' - http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920027072.do . - It's a good read and will for sure help you achieve what you want in the future.

If there is no severity I would remove it completely. - If you believe this answers your question, don't forget to mark the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your use case but this will print the result as you want. You don't need to iterate through the variables. simply map everything you want in the first place.

```
class event():
    def __init__(self, description, priority):
        self.description = description
        self.priority = priority
        self.severity = priority

        pass

    _translateMap = {
       'description': 'message',
       'priority' : 'priority',
       'severity': 'severity'
    }

    def translate(self):
       result = {}
       for key, value in self._translateMap.items():
               result[key] = getattr(self, key)

       return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event1 = event('blahblah','3')
    print (event1.translate())
```